# How to plot below x axis area with a different color in python?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, time-series

I am plotting a time series in python and for better visualization, I want to plot below axis area with a different color. Below is the code I am using.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(list2,spi1,color = 'black')
plt.ylabel('Standardized precipitation index')
plt.xlabel('Time (years)')
plt.show()
```

Please help me to make it correct.
Here is the plot-
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "below axis area"? Do you want to plot the values below zero as red?

Comment: Yes, I want negative values to be plotted with different color but not as scatter plots. If there is a negative value in this series, The line plot using incoming and outgoing line from that point makes a area below x axis. I want that area to be of different color and positive area to be of different color. Thanks

Comment: There is an example showing how to colour a line based on another variable: https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/multicolored_line.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the issue with plt.fill_between library. Below is the code and correct graph. Thank you all for quick responses and kind help.

```
y1positive=np.array(spi1)>=0
y1negative = np.array(spi1)<=0
plt.fill_between(list2,spi1,y2=0,where=y1positive,
color='green',alpha=0.5,interpolate=False)
plt.fill_between(list2,spi1,y2=0,where=y1negative,
color='red',alpha=0.5,interpolate=False)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This was the exact thing I wanted to plot

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the plot image and not caring for the logic behind, I have a very bad idea.

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y = np.random.rand(30)

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1)
sca(ax1)
ax1.plot(y, color='k')
ax1.set(ylim=(.5, 1))
ax1.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)

ax2.plot(y, color='r')
ax2.set(ylim=(0, .5))
ax2.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you very much!